# Make a GtkButton look depressed

Tags: c, gtk

So I have a shape drawing program, with a toolbar with buttons for box, circle, segment, etc.
If you click a shape button (such as the box button), you can drag the mouse to draw that kind of shape. I didn't use toggle buttons because I don't want it so that if you draw a box you have to "untoggle" the box button before you can "toggle" the circle button, for example. However, I'm trying to make it so that when you have clicked a shape button, it looks "depressed" so you know what shape you're drawing until you click another button.

I try to make it look depressed by putting this in the clicked callback:

```
gtk_widget_set_state_flags(button, GTK_STATE_FLAG_ACTIVE, TRUE);
```

However, it's not working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tell the GtkButton that web applications are taking over the world, and it will be depressed.

Comment: ^^ LOL. Funniest thing I've read all day!

Comment: @JohnZwinck: much better than the "witty" comment I had in mind.

Comment: Put a frowny face on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to use a toggle button, but programmatically untoggle them when the user is done drawing the box. This way you don't have to fight the API or hurt any buttons' feelings.